# How add paragraph after ColumnText in iText Java?

Tags: java, itext

```
    Rectangle[] COLUMNS = {
            new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806),
            new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806)
    };

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("CNPJ da Empresa:");
    p.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    Phrase x = new Phrase("10964783711987");
    p.add(x);

    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Telefone de contato:");
    p1.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    x = new Phrase("(81) 3271-2320");
    p1.add(x);

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);

    int side_of_the_page = 0;
    ct.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);

    ct.addElement(p);

    ct.go();

    ct.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[1]);
    ct.addElement(p1);

    ct.go();

    Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("Alunos participantes da empresa");
    p3.setSpacingBefore(100);
    document.add(p3);

    document.close();
```

The texts in two columns are ok, but when add new paragraph, it overlaps the columnText.
I need add this new paragraph outside the columnText and continue fill document.
Thanks the help.[image]

Comment: Well, you have to decide, either you manually do the layout in the main page area (by explicitly adding content to the canvas, via `ColumnText` in your case) or you leave the layout process to itext (by adding content to `document`).  How about adding the first two paragraphs to a borderless table and adding that table to the document instead of the canvas? Or alternatively removing the `ColumnText` area from the main page area by changing the margins?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @mlk. Could you please show me a example for these suggestions? I'm a new iText's enthusiast, I started two days ago and I don't know much about this library.